# Align a LinearLayout at the bottom of a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have these nested layouts and i want to put a LinearLayout anchored to the bottom (internally) of the first RelativeLayout but i don't know how to do it. Can someone help me? I want something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSA4d.jpg

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.35">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add id to each view and then explain the problem. Question is not clear

Comment: I added an image of how the layout should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `layout_weight` work properly set `android:layout_height="0dp"` for both relative layouts

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

change 10dp to whatever suits you. 
I set the colors just to distinguish the layouts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align a view to the bottom of a relative layout you need to use 
    `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

in the view that is going to be stuck at the bottom of the relative

Answer (score 0):

Since you need `weight`too in your UI so This will work for you

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Align LinearLayout to the bottom using id.
take the id of relative layout and then align LinearLayout  to the bottom at the end of relative layout id.